JavaFX scale up size
49
I have a JavaFX application which has only one FXML file. I have AnchorPane with Image (1920x1080). When I run, I want to see full image, but the program automatically scales up my AnchorPane. It happened with my StackPane too.
My Code:
FXML
<AnchorPane prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" stylesheets="@../CSS/Account/RecoverAccount.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.group3.cinemabooking.Client.ClientViewController">
    <ImageView fitHeight="1080.0" fitWidth="1920.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
        <Image url="@../../../../Images/universal.jpg" />
    </ImageView>
</AnchorPane>

App.java
package org.group3.cinemabooking;

public class App extends Application {
    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Client/ClientView.fxml"));
        scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 1920, 1080);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Login");
        stage.show();
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String url) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(url + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void setRoot(String fxml, String title) throws Exception {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) scene.getWindow();
        primaryStage.setTitle(title);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

I tried to fix that but can't. What I want to see is when I run, JavaFX will not scale up my file. This is when I run my code:
enter image description here.
As you can see, the picture is a little bigger.

Here is a post about showing an image: How to fill an image in an imageView in javafx?. But, it uses an ImageView.
